# Macbook Pro mid 2014 battery lasting only 2/3 hours (300 cycles)

Tags: battery, macbook, macbook-pro, battery-life, macbook-pro-retina

I just can't figure out why my battery is draining so fast, using it only for browsing/watching videos.

Any idea?

[image: system information screenshot]

Comment: Original battery? 9 years is a very, very long time for a battery. After about 5 years it really makes no difference at all how many cycles it claims.

Comment: Try a replacement battery from Dr Battery (Amazon). I got a battery for my elderly X230 Laptop (10 years) and it works fine.

Comment: Browsing and watching videos are not exactly low-power tasks. Many websites today have tremendous complexity that will really stress your PC, even just from scrolling. // Just some anecdata: my Late '13 MBP still lasts many hours even after more cycles.

Answer (score 2):

The Lithium-Ion batteries used in most devices (? all Lithium batteries in 2014) suffer degradation that is unavoidable, and you are seeing the effect of degradation of the battery over time.

[This article](https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries) has a lot of details about Lithium-ion battery degradation - have a look at table 3.

An unrealistic best case - a brand new battery stored at 40 percent in a fridge at 0c would be about 65-70% of original capacity - and a typical case would be closer to 35% - and that's for an unused battery - so what you are seeing is entirely reasonable.